# VuePress Sidebar does not render

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

```
//config.js
sidebar:[

          {
              title: 'Group 1',
              path:'/foo/',
              collapsable: false,
              sidebarDepth: 1,
              children: [
                 '/guide/', 
                '/installation/',
                '/Tips & Trcks/' ]
          },
```

//my folder structure

[image]

The problem: My sidebar shows nothing.

[image]

Comment: Your post is pretty short. You have 3 photos and one phrase. Try to tell us what you tried and what's wrong. Also, tell us your expecting behavior. I know that you already know how to write a post because you have 12.2k points. Please update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **solution**:

```
     sidebar: [
        '/',
        {
            title: 'Guide',
            collapsable: false,
            children: [ 
            ['/guide/Frontend','Frontend'],
            ['/guide/Backend' , 'Backend' ]

        },
```

Explanation:

```
 ['/guide/Frontend','Frontend'],
```

the `'/guide/Frontend'` is the path, the `'Frontend'` (you can name it whatever you want) is what you want to call it in the sidebar so the sidebar title doesn't have to be read in 'absolute path' format.

[image]